# How to animate like button numbers with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to add effect to jQuery's text() function. I have this code:

`$('#A1').text(Number($('#A1').text()) + 1);`

This code changes the value of `<span>` tag.

How I can add effect like this?

[image]

I have tried:

```
$('#A1').text(Number($('#A1').text()) + 1).slideDown('slow');
```

but I'm missing something...

Comment: Please share with us the best try (code) you have

Comment: `$('#A1').text(Number($('#A1').text()) + 1).slideDown('slow'); `something like this :)

Comment: Take a look at the [Odometer](http://github.hubspot.com/odometer/) library, which seems to do exactly what you're after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a simple animation with jQuery's `animate`. For example:

```
var duration = 500;
var $d = $('#div');
var $s = $('#span');
$d.click(function() {
    var $newNum = $('<span>').text('3').css({
        position: 'absolute',
        bottom: $s.height()
    }).appendTo($d);

    $newNum.animate({
        bottom: 0
    }, {
        duration: duration,
    });

    $s.animate({
        top: $s.height(),
        height: 0
    }, {
        duration: duration,
        complete: function() { $s.remove(); }
    });
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<div id='div' style='position:relative'>Amount: 1<span id='span' style='position:absolute'>2</span></div>
```

**[Here's a JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/QHX2M/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

I've found **Doorknob solution too hard to implement in a real-world use**, where data are pulled and sent to database due to the hardcoded HTML structure

**Here is my 2c:**

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/mewaj/2/edit)**

```
<span data-likes="8" data-userliked="false">Like </span>
```

In the above HTML you just fill-in the info from DB into the `data-*` attributes and you're done.

```
$('[data-likes]').each(function() {      
  var voteOnce = false, // Set to "true" to allow only one user vote !!!
      errorMessage = "You already liked this." ,
      votePos = "append", // Use: "prepend" or "append""
      $el = $(this).css({display:"inline-block", cursor:"pointer"}),
      data = $el.data(),
      s1CSS = {position:"relative", display:"inline-block",
               overflow:"hidden", verticalAlign:"bottom"},
      s2CSS = {position:"absolute", right:0}; 

  // ////////////////////////      
  var $s1 = $("<span />", {css: s1CSS}),
      $s2 = $("<span />", {css: s2CSS, text:data.likes});
  $el[votePos]( $s1.append( $s2 ) );
  var w = $s2.width(), h = $s2.height();  
  $s1.css({width:w, height:h});      
  $el.click(function(){
    if(voteOnce && data.userliked){
      return alert( errorMessage );
    }
    data.userliked = true; // (Send also info to database!)
    data.likes++;
    var $sX = $s2;   // Remember old span2
    $s2 = $("<span />",{text: data.likes, css:{top:-h}}).css(s2CSS);
    $s1.append($s2); // Append new span
    w = $s2.width();
    h = $s2.height();
    $s1.animate({width:w, height:h});
    $s2.animate({top:0});
    $sX.animate({top:h},function(){ $(this).remove(); });
  });    
});
```

**That's it.**

To get you a picture of what the above does so you can better understand or style your elements, it creates this HTML structure automagically:

```
<span data-likes="8" data-userliked="false">
    Like
    <span>            <!-- THIS IS $s1, has overflow and relative pos. -->
       <span>8</span> <!-- THIS IS $s2, with absolute position -->
    </span>
</span>
```

Once the user clicks what happens is:

```
<span data-likes="9" data-userliked="true">
    Like
    <span>            
       <span>8</span> <!-- this becomes $sX, animate it to top:h and remove-->
       <span>9</span> <!-- new appended $s2, animate it to top:0 -->
    </span>
</span>
```

If you want to additionally style the `<span>` elements use:

```
span[data-likes]{ }             /* The main SPAN */
span[data-likes] > span{ }      /* The relative SPAN parent */
span[data-likes] > span span{ } /* The absolute SPANS with numbers */
```